# Google Tag Manager - Multiple Firing Rules if url contains

Tags: magento, macros, google-tag-manager

I'd like to ask how best to set this up in GTM. I have a custom html tag that should only fire if:
1) visitor came from a link tagged with www.example.com/example/?affiliate=xxxxx
2) This tag only fires if the user hits the success page.

Comment: what did you mean by "hits the success page". Is there a redirection from the "example.com/example/?affiliate=xxxxx" page or do you change your screens using JS and CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the {{referrer}} built-in macro to return the referring page, and then create your rule to fire your custom HTML tag as follows:

Fire tag if

1. {{URL}} equals {success page URL} (or {{URL Path}} equals {success page URL path})
2. {{referrer}} contains "www.example.com/example/?affiliate=xxxxx"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

1. Add a rule to check the `{{url}}  - contain - example.com/example/?affiliate=xxxxx`

If you don't do any redirection to the success page (we can't use the same Tag if you redirect the page and it will change the above URL)

2. Add a rule for the Button click event (Submit). To do that you must add a click Listener  too.

Otherwise, If you redirect the page after user coming through example.com/example/?affiliate=xxxxx URL, you have to setup a cookie from the backend and assign it to a JS variable.
Otherwise you wouldn't  be able to track the affiliate ID after page redirection.

Cheers,